# Non-static method getText() can not be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I have written the following code, but continually get a 'non-static method getText() can not be referenced from a static context' error.

Could someone help get me on the right track here?

```
public class ISBNText extends JTextField
{  
   protected static String bookNum;
   protected JTextField  bookText; 
   public ISBNText() 
   {
       super(20);
       bookText = new JTextField();
   }   
   public String getISBN()
   {           
      String bookNum = ISBNText.getText();
      return bookNum;
   }
   private String validateISBN(String bookNum)
}
```

Comment: This URL may help explain this (and other) compile time messages.

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html#NONSTATICCANTBEREF

Comment: Which text do you want, the one in `this` (the ISBNText object) or the text in bookText? Also, why do you have one JTextField subclass creating another JTextField as a member? It seems rather odd.

Comment: I don't know, I agree it seems odd. Homework assignments can be rather strange. I wrote almost literally what the assignment asks for, and I believe I have done it the way it is asked.

Comment: I would venture that the assignment didn't ask specifically for that, but we'll never know if we don't see the actual assignment requirements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line:

```
String bookNum = ISBNText.getText();
```

should just be:

```
String bookNum = getText();
```

which is implicitly:

```
String bookNum = this.getText();
```

The call `ISBNText.getText()` is trying to call it as if it's a static method - i.e. associated with the type rather than with any specific *instance* of the type. That clearly doesn't make sense, as the text *is* associated with an instance of the type. The two alternatives I've shown you are equivalent, finding the text of the `ISBNText` that `getISBN` has been called on.

Comment: oh.........thank you.    270K?  Wow.  So what exactly (other than being wrong), does the String bookNum=ISBN.getText(); do?  Why does it cause the static error to be thrown?

Comment: @unit: When you precede a method (or variable) with a class name, like ISBNText, the compiler thinks you're trying to refer to a static. If a non-static element by the same name exists, you get the error you ran into.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `getText` as though it were a static.  Remove `ISBNText` from in front of it in your `getISBN` method.

It looks like you're also redundantly instantiating an additional `JTextField`.  The class you're writing *is* a `JTextField` and you don't need the additional one you're creating:

```
protected JTextField bookText;  // get rid of this
public ISBNText() 
{
   super(20);
   bookText = new JTextField();  // and this
```

Answer (score 3):

The method `getText()` is not static and should be called on the instance of the object.

```
public String getISBN()
{           
   String bookNum = this.getText();
   return bookNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you're calling ISBNText.getText(), but the getText() method is not a static method. Just remove the ISBNText from the beginning of that call, and you should be good.